# The IPhone Development Program: what happens?

Tags: iphone

I applied a week ago to Apple via internet to join the Iphone Development Program, and sent 'em my $99.00.

I was of the impression that generally, the response was quick.  However, other than an email acknowledging my purchase, I have not seen anything at all.

Would some kind soul explain to me what to expect, and when?

Thanks in advance for any information.

John Doner

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a phone call that verifies your credentials in about 2-4 weeks and then you're good, ie. you can get your code provisioning certificates and start submitting apps.

Comment: A phone call? I didn't get a phone call? My account was ready the next day.

Comment: Mine took 4 weeks and I had to fax them in my company certificate of formation. why 4 weeks vs 1 day? Apple world renown transparency at its best ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend emailing apple (devenroll@apple.com) or use the contact form here: http://developer.apple.com/contact/

I registered a few weeks ago and received my activation within a few hours - no phone call from apple or anything beyond the initial $99.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario as you last summer and had to call up Apple Developer Tech Support.  They finished setting me up right away.

The phone number to call is found here:  http://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.html

Comment: Where is this phone number? I don't see it anywhere.
Also the FAQ says: "You can check the status of your iPhone Developer Program enrollment by logging into the iPhone Dev Center and reviewing the Program Enrollment section located on the upper right side of the screen." Do you (or does anyone) know where this is? I can't find it either.

Comment: I added a link to the phone # page.

Answer (score 0):

I initially signed up for the iPhone developer program when registration was opened wider after the initial rush.  It took about a week, I never had to talk to anybody on the phone and got the acceptance email.  Once you get the email you need to activate it, but that will all be explained in the EMail.

I do most of my non-accelerometer development in the simulator and double check everything on my iPod after things are working in the simulator.